# Difference in Visual Studio versions

Tags: visual-studio-2010, visual-studio-2008, visual-studio

I would like to understand some fundamental VS version differences.

What is the difference between Visual Studio 2008 and Visual Studio 2008 Team System? Does the Team System 2008 include VS2008, TFS 2008 & Team Explorer 2008?
Furthermore, what is the difference betwene Team System 2008 and Team Suite 2008?

I believe there are no more Team Suites or Team Systems in 2010?

Does Visual Studio Ultimate 2010 include all Team System components, like TFS 2010 & Team Explorer 2010, so in effect it is like an upgrade of Visual Studio 2008 Team System? Or does TFS 2010 & Team Explorer 2010 need to be installed separately?

Comment: Also, as Visual Studio 2008 Team System become Visual Studio 2010 Ultimate?

Answer (score 2):

For Visual Studio 2008 this [comparison chart](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/en/details.aspx?familyid=727BCFB0-B575-47AB-9FD8-4EE067BB3A37&displaylang=en) should give you everything you need as it is very detailed in its approach. Visual Studio 2008 Team Suite encompasses the standalone editions with regard to Team System such as Architect, Development, Test, etc...while also providing a copy of Team Foundation Server.

For Visual Studio 2010 you can go to the [default site](http://www.microsoft.com/visualstudio/en-us/products/2010-editions/product-comparison) for Visual Studio which will provide comparisons across the products.

All versions with regard to Visual Studio 2010 come with Team Foundation Server. In addition all versions of Visual Studio 2010 have the ability to connect to a TFS as outlined in this [SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/915995/visual-studio-2010-team-explorer); there is no separate download for Team Explorer as there once was with Visual Studio 2008.

Comment: Yes but it doesnt hightlight the difference between Visual Studio 2008 Team System and Visual Studio 2008 Team Suite

Comment: @karthik Added edit...Visual Studio 2008 Team Suite encompasses the standalone editions with regard to Team System such as Architect, Development, Test, etc...while also providing a copy of Team Foundation Server